# How to override ArrayAdapter add method to add image and textview to it? I have custom array adapter class

Tags: java, android, json, listview, android-listview

I am successfully adding image with text when I initialize adapter object and set it as listview adapter but I want to add more items to it when I get more data from internet which includes image. I am retrieving information from internet using json which includes image url.
Here is my adapter code

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] web;
    private final Integer[] imageId;
    public CustomList(Activity context,
                      String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_single, web);
        this.context = context;
        this.web = web;
        this.imageId = imageId;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        txtTitle.setText(web[position]);

        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

I want to add more items to it after I have set the array adapter.(images with text) I know how to add text only.

Comment: Call "notifyDataSetChanged();" on your adapter when you receive more data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest to use an `ArrayList` for the `String` and `Integer` objects, instead of normal arrays. With this you can more easily append data.

In your `Activity`, you keep the reference to the `String` and `Integer` `ArrayList` objects you pass to the Adapter. When you receive new date, you simply add this data to the lists.

When the data is updated, you should call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method of the adapter to display the data in your view.

--EDIT--

Another suggestion: you should recycle the views already created in the `getView` method. You can do this by checking if the provided contentview (the second argument) is null. This will greatly improve the performance of larger `ListViews`

```
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(view == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
         }
            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
            txtTitle.setText(web[position]);

            imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
            return view;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this at the beginning of your `getView` method:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null); //Try both with ", true" and without.
```

Also, try to build and pass a Drawable object to `imageView.setImageResource(....);`